# what does usage between raise and increase?

Tags: american-english

I want to write a sentence like of the following.
I don't have idea what is more prefer word between raise and increase.
What does usage increase and raise?

1. When the day raised my salary was my happiest day one of my life.
2. When the day increased my salary was my happiest day one of my life.
3. When they raised my salary was happiest day.
4. When they increased my salary was happiest day.

Comment: This looks like proofreading to me. None of the suggested sentences are credible, for a variety of reasons, but any difference between *raise* and *increase* is irrelevant in this context. A reasonable version (primarly based on OP's example #1) would be *"The day **they** raised my salary was **the** happiest day of my life"* (delete ***when*** and ***one***, and add highlighted words).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about the act of the salary being increased - eg if taking about pay rises, you can put the emphasis on the increase as an event

> The day my salary was increased was the happiest day of my life.
>   Or
>   The day my boss raised my salary was the happiest day of my life

Whereas if you're talking about life events, rather than specifically about money, 
you may wish to put the emphasis on the day

> The day my salary increased was the happiest day of my life.

Or more informally

> The day I got a raise was the happiest day of my life.

Comment: Did you mean that I can use increase and raise without any limitation?

Comment: You can use either, but they are used in slightly different ways. Your salary **is** increased. Whereas you **get** a raise. There are exceptions to this, and the uses can be mixed, but those are the 'best' ways to use each word.